# How to modify a function to wait for a line to finish execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this angularJS function

```
$scope.myFunc = ()  => {
        myModule.getConfig().update(params);
        myModule.go();

        myModule.log('ok');
    };
```

and the go function

```
go: function () {
            $state.go('myFunc', options);
        },
```

myModule.go() is calling an API and taking some time. How can I modify this code to call myModule.log() only when the previous line has finished?

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough information about how `go()` works for us to determine what mechanisms it has to signal that it is finished (assuming it has any).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @Quentin you are correct, I updated the question. it uses uirouter/angularjs I think.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming `myModule.go` takes a callback, you could use a Promise.

```
$scope.myFunc = async () => {
    try {
        myModule.getConfig().update(params);
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => myModule.go(resolve));
        myModule.log('ok');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks but I can't use async/await as the required module is not installed.